# Google Compute Engine wordpress is not installed

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create an instance with WordPress and phpMyAdmin using [Click to Deploy WordPress on Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/wordpress/click-to-deploy). The WordPress instance is created successfully without any errors. But there seems to be some discrepancy in the documentation provided.

It is mentioned that after deployment I should enable HTTP traffic. I did that and the IP address provided gets enabled. 
*In the next step, where it tells to ssh into the instance and change mysqladmin password, the default password was blank (which I found out after many attempts of entering the provided password) and not the password which is provided in the deployment page*.

After changing the password, according to the documentation, it should prompt me with further installation steps which involves creating a WordPress account and so. However, that never happens. *When I open the IP address, it just opens the default apache welcome page*. Also it's mentioned in the docs that,

> Access phpMyAdmin If you chose to install phpMyAdmin, access it at
>   /phpmyadmin

*But when I try to open /phpmyadmin, it shows a 404 error. I've marked phpMyAdmin when creating the instance, and it shows phpMyAdmin installed 
true in the console*.

Can anyone point me where I went wrong? I'm fairy new at using Google Compute Engine so please bear with me if this is a trivial mistake.

P.S: The configuration is default one which is mentioned in the documentation linked above.

Comment: Google App Engine (a PaaS solution, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) is not the same as Google Compute Engine (a IaaS solution). The question seems to suggest you're referring to Google Compute Engine. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes Dan, I'm referring to Compute Engine.

Comment: I have reported this to our engineering team. In the meantime, you can deploy WordPress on GCE instance using Bitnami Cloud Launcher (https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress?q=bitnam).

Comment: I just encountered the same problem.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue has been fixed. I have confirmed by deploying WordPress using Google Click to Deploy and was able to access the phpMyAdmin. Can you confirm to see if its working for your as well.

Comment: @Faizan, Yes I can confirm it as working now. I too am able to access phpMyAdmin. Thank you.

Comment: Ok perfect, I'm glad to know your issue is resolved.